# metro boundler does not work - expo/react native

Tags: react-native, path, expo, metro-bundler

I want to run a react native app by those commands:

```
npm i -g expo-cli
expo init myapp
cd myapp
npm start
```

but I get the following error and the metro boundler not work:

```
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Error: spawn powershell ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nathan-hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-22T14_48_10_269Z-debug.log
```

I added this to the path:

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

but I still get the error above

Comment: are you running cmd as admin?

Comment: no, why should I ?

Comment: it makes a lot changes, and delete/add files.

Comment: I tried the process in the cmd as an admin but when it ask me to run npm install, there were found 11 low severity vulnerabilities and runing npm audit fix didnt solve it

Comment: that's the issue with the packages that you have in your package.json, aka the stuff that you chose to install with your project, or it's part of the expo init.

Comment: I typically don't worry about those unless it's a med/high severity.

Comment: thanks, I found the solution as follows in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

ok, that was the solution:
the problem was:

```
Error: spawn powershell ENOENT
```

1. so I need to add:

   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

to the path.

2. I openned Windows PowerShell **as admin** and run:

   `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force`
3. run `npm start` again in the cmd and then metro boundler was openned

- I did that commands yesterday but somehow it didnt work, guess I have missed something.
  The full explanation can be found here:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=nfX7HtNiCZI